# Getting black screen when added ExoPlayer into GLSurfaceView

Tags: java, android, video, exoplayer

I have one GLsurfaceview and video SurfaceView when I added Surfaceview into GLSurfaceView for playing video and result is I am getting black screen instead of video screen. I am getting Audio properly but video screen will not display and it remains black during the whole video.

Both are used for different purpose GLSurfaceView for Page turn while Video surfaceview for ExoPlayer.

GLSurfaceView :

```
    public class CurlView extends GLSurfaceView implements View.OnTouchListener,
        CurlRenderer.Observer {

        }
```

Video SurfaceView of ExoPlayer :

```
    public class VideoSurfaceView extends SurfaceView {


    }
```

Comment: please provide enough code to debug your problem : logcat of the fullprocess with the Exoplayer debug messages, & your full implementation of exoplayer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this For VideoSurfaceView

```
surfaceView = (VideoSurfaceView) view.findViewById(R.id.surface_view);
surfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);
surfaceView.setZOrderOnTop(true);
```